# updating mongoose set subdocument

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have an ordered list. I'd like to add one to the list in the middle. I'm sorting without a problem, but modifying seems to be a bit more difficult. The main goal is to find all numbers that are equal to the one sent or greater and update. I would update them as I find them, but I cannot have a function in a loop.

```
function updateNumbersAfterArticles(searchableid, number){
    var m_searchableid = new ObjectId(searchableid);
    m_Kbase_data.findOne( {_id : m_searchableid}, function(err, kbase_data){
    if (kbase_data.Steps.length === 1){
        var updated_step = new m_KbaseScript_schema({step: kbase_data.Steps[0].step + 1, description : kbase_data.Steps[0].description, image : kbase_data.Steps[0].image});
        m_Kbase_data.update({_id : m_searchableid, 'Step._id' : kbase_data.Steps[0]._id },
                {$set: { "Steps.$": updated_step }},
                function(err, updateRows){
                    //if (err) res.status(500);
                    console.log(updateRows);
                }
            );
        return;
    }
    else{
        var updated_step2 = [];
        for (var i = 1; i < kbase_data.Steps.length; i++) {
            if (kbase_data.Steps[i].step >= number){
                console.log("pushed");
                updated_step2.push( new m_KbaseScript_schema({step: kbase_data.Steps[i].step + 1, description : kbase_data.Steps[i].description, image : kbase_data.Steps[i].image}));
            }
        }
        console.log(updated_step2);
        m_Kbase_data.update({_id : m_searchableid, },
                {$set: { "Steps.$": updated_step2 }},
                function(err, updateRows){
                    //if (err) res.status(500);
                    console.log(updateRows);
                }
            );
    }
});
```

}

When I run it, I can see all of the pushes. They appear to update correctly. However, I'm not getting the database updated.

Answer (score 0):

this is how I got it working. (I haven't tested with one object yet):

```
function updateNumbersAfterArticles(searchableid, number){
    var m_searchableid = new ObjectId(searchableid);
    m_Kbase_data.findOne( {_id : m_searchableid}, function(err, kbase_data){

        if (kbase_data.Steps.length === 1){
            var updated_step = new m_KbaseScript_schema({step: kbase_data.Steps[0].step + 1, description : kbase_data.Steps[0].description, image : kbase_data.Steps[0].image});
            m_Kbase_data.update({_id : m_searchableid, 'Step._id' : kbase_data.Steps[0]._id },
                    {$set: { "Steps.$": updated_step }},
                    function(err, updateRows){
                        //if (err) res.status(500);
                        console.log(updateRows);
                    }
                );
            return;
        }
        else{
            var updated_step2 = kbase_data.Steps;
            for (var i = 1; i < kbase_data.Steps.length; i++) {
                if (kbase_data.Steps[i].step >= number){
                    //console.log("pushed");
                    kbase_data.Steps[i].step = kbase_data.Steps[i].step + 1;
                    kbase_data.markModified('Steps');
                }
            }
            kbase_data.save();


        }
    });
}
```